# Angular Daterangepicker Change Locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is about the widget from daterangepicker.com. The problem I am facing is that when I try to change the locale by changing **options** $scope.opts = {...} the **ng-model** $scope.date = {...} binds before this happens and always uses the previous locale.

```
<input date-range-picker id="datepick"
    autoUpdateInput="true"
    name="datepick"
    class="form-control date-picker"
    type="text"
    options="opts"
    ng-model="date"
required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

component.html

```
>   <div class="row">
>     <div class="input-field col s12">
>       <input formControlName="birthDate" id="birthDate" type="date" class="datepicker" materialize="pickadate" [materializeParams]="[{
> format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
>         closeOnSelect: true, selectMonths: true, selectYears: true, today: '',
>         max: true, onSet: onSetDatepicker }]">
>       <label for="birthDate">Birthday*</label>
>     </div>   </div>
```

component.ts

```
>  onSetDatepicker(date) {
>     if (date.select) {
>       $('#birthDate').pickadate().pickadate('picker').close();
>     }   }
```